# How to display the double field in Excel using JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

How can I set the text field as double for generating an *Excel* report but my add field as a string? I want to print the text field as double in *Excel* using *JasperReports 4.7*.

```
<fieldDescription>
    <![CDATA[/REPORT/CHEQUEAMOUNT]]>
</fieldDescription>

<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Double">
    <![CDATA[new Double($F{CHEQUEAMOUNT})]]>
</textFieldExpression>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to force this parameter in the exporter:

```
JExcelApiExporter exporter = new JExcelApiExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JExcelApiExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
<textField pattern="#,###,##0.00">
    <reportElement>
        <propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.formula"><![CDATA[String.valueOf($F{CHEQUEAMOUNT})]]></propertyExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[Double.valueOf(0)]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Remember to use java variables names in camel case: chequeAmount